# jquery not refreshing controls

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, I have a weird behavior issue on an mvc view that I am working on. The form is for employee onboarding, so it collects information about the new employee. I have a dropdown list of job titles that is strongly typed.

The weird part of this is that this does not work upon the first change of the Job Title dropdown. It does everything but show the checked box. It does work fine though for subsequent change events. I have tracked the firing events using alert boxes. When those alerts show, it all works. When I comment out the alerts, the weird behavior returns.

The logic is as follows:

1. A job title is selected; jquery detects the change event.
2. A call to the controller is made and the controller returns a partial view comprised of one field (SelectedAppsList).
3. Jquery function clears the Application(s) Checkboxes
4. Jquery is called to check checkboxes of Applications based upon the returned values in SelectedAppsList.

Wizard View:

```
    $("#JobId").change(function () {
            //alert($("#JobId").val());

            // Check the Apps Based Upon the Job Title
            var jobId = $("#JobId").val();
            $("#dvApps").load('@(Url.Action("GetApps", "ESRWizards", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?jobId=' + jobId);
            AutoCheckSelectedApps();
        }));

 function AutoCheckSelectedApps() {
            ClearSelectedApps();
            //alert("Selecting Apps...");
            var apps = $("#SelectedAppsList").val().split('|');

            for (var i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
                //alert(apps[i]);
                if (apps[i] != "") {
                    $('input[type="checkbox"][id="SelectedApps_' + apps[i] + '"]').attr('checked', true);
                }
            }
        };

        function ClearSelectedApps() {
            //alert("Cleared...");
            $('input[type="checkbox"][id^="SelectedApps_"]').attr('checked', false);
        }
```

Wizard View Form Controls Involved:

```
    `@Html.DropDownList("JobId", String.Empty)`
    `<input type="checkbox" name="SelectedApps_@item.Id" id="SelectedApps_@item.Id" value="@item.Id" />`
```

and partial view below.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult GetApps(int jobId)
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedAppsList = null;
        var AppList = db.JobApps.Where(m => m.JobId == jobId).OrderBy(v => v.AppId);
        foreach (var item in AppList)
        {
            ViewBag.SelectedAppsList += item.AppId.ToString() + "|";
        }

        return PartialView("_Apps");
    }
```

Partial View _Apps

```
    @model ECSR.Models.ESRWizard
    @if(ViewBag.SelectedAppsList != null)
    {
       @Html.TextBox("SelectedAppsList", (string)ViewBag.SelectedAppsList)
    }
    else
    {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAppsList)
    }
```

I am guessing that this is a possible refresh issue, so I tried various refresh commands on the checkboxes to no avail. This is a long form so I stripped out the non-related form fields. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can attach the event handler closer to the element required? Attaching a change handler to the whole document and waiting for it to bubble all the way up the DOM could be a problem - just a quick observation. I've ran into similar issues with select elements and the change event before, but don't remember specifics right now.

Comment: That's how I normally do. I had changed it to document during testing. The regular event handle is: `$("#JobId").change(function () {}`

Comment: Do you get anything by doing `console.log(jobId)` on the first change?

Comment: No, but if I uncomment the 'alert($("#JobId").val());' I get the expected JobId.

Comment: Just trying to narrow it down some more... I uncommented just the `alert("Selecting Apps...");` in jquery function AutoCheckSelectedApps(). After I click the ok button on the alert, the check boxes that are supposed to be checked are.

Comment: Ok, first of all the `load` function has a callback as a last parameter (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). So if you want to do something with the partial that you load from server (at least that how I understood it), you should put that logic inside that callback, i.e. call `AutoCheckSelectedApps()`

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin: That was it! Thank you. The call to the custom function was not in the load command like it should have been. I had it on a seperate line below.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. :)